# Unable to use quicktime player to do screen recording on my Mac

Tags: macbook, quicktime

It used to work, because I distinctly remember using it. But for some reasons, it no longer does. I was trying to use quicktime player to do a quick screen recording. I opened quicktime player, I chose screen recording and then I chose click all the settings I want until when I finish recording and tries to save it. Then I couldn't fine the save button! I [image]

Comment: Did you close the recorded movie window? As soon as you hit Stop, the movie ought to open. From there you can Save. if you close it, it will prompt to save too. The only time the "New Screen Recording" menu item is greyed is whilst you are actually recording one, or just before you start recording. Best guess without any additional evidence is that your menu bar is too full to show the stop button. Try removing some of the clutter from it.

Comment: There is no stop button, at least I didn’t find one

Comment: Then back to my best guess - your menu bar is too full for it to show. Get rid of a few of those.